# StreamWriter and FileStream errors on file create

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Save ActionResult in my Controller that is set up to use StreamWriter. The code works perfectly, for saving to a file that exists.

Save Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Save(string fileName,  string startTemplateUrl, string html)
    {
        string directoryname = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        var lines =  html;
        var helper = (Server.MapPath(directoryname));
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(helper, filename)))
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(lines);
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I am now working on a file creation and from what i have read you can do this with StreamWriter although when I try to implement it, it says it cannot be found. Which tells me it is looking for a file instead of creating it.

So I tried to implement this using FileInfo. It appears that it has everything it needs but just doesn't save it. Below is my latest code. It does not like the

```
fs.Write(lines);
```

I had a try catch block. on  this and it had the same results. That it cannot find it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create (string fileName, string startTemplateUrl, string html)
    {
        string directoryname = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        var lines = html;
        var helper = (Server.MapPath(directoryname));
        var file = "Test\\" + filename;
        var pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(helper, "Test\\", filename);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pathString);

            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }
            using (FileStream fs = fi.Create())
            {
                fs.Write(lines);
                return View();
            }

    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Update:

This is the message I get. Below the message I have the actual string to the directory copied from folder explorer..

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Scott\source\repos\HMIBuilder\HMIBuilder\Files\HMIBuider\Test\Test2.html'.

C:\Users\Scott\source\repos\HMIBuilder\HMIBuilder\Files\HMIBuilder\Test
```

Update:

I need to look at my code better! This is fixed.. The code at the very top works perfectly for both save and create. The problem was in the javascript code variables that i was feeding it. A Typo... If you look at the above comparison, which I did not catch myself, too many long nights I suppose, HMIBuilder is spelled HMIBuider... in the error.

Comment: Does the folder that you are trying to create the file in exist? You have to make sure that exists, or create it as a separate step, otherwise file creation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, "filename.txt")))
```

would create a new file, if needed.

Your problem may be the `Test` directory and `CreateDirectory` is here to help.

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

---

If we put the writing to the file and creating directories together it could look like the following snippet.

```
var path = "./MyFiles/SpecialFiles";
var filename = "thisIsAVerySpecialFile.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
//Create a new file or overwrite existing (i.e. *not* append)
using (var f = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, filename)))
{
    f.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

Without `Directory.CreateDirectory` the code results in `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` with `'Could not find a part of the path '(...)'.`

Comment: The issue is not the directory. It exists. It just comes back through debugging that i cannot find or find part of the "url string i give it". however it is in fact there. I tried the string with ending it with just the folder and with the "new file" name..